# Split a PHP while Loop into seperete divs

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to output all client logos, but limit each section `<section>` to 16 logos. At the moment, the HTML outputted isn't correct but for the life of me I cannot figure our where my code is wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
<?php $logototal = count( get_sub_field('bp_client_logos') ); //Get a total count of the logos ?>

    <?php 
    $count = "0"; 
        if( have_rows('bp_client_logos') ) :
            $i = 1; 
                while ( have_rows('bp_client_logos') ) : the_row(); ?>

    <?php
        $clientindex = $i;
            if( $clientindex == "1" || ($clientindex-1) %16 == "0" ) :
    ?>

    <div class="section general-section section-<?php echo $title; ?> section-count-<?php echo $count; ?>" data-anchor="section-<?php echo $count; ?>" style="<?php echo $bg_background; ?>">       
        <div class="row small-up-4 medium-up-8 large-up-8 align-middle">

    <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="column client-logo-grid">
                <?php 
                    $image = get_sub_field('bp_client_logo');
                    // Vars
                    $url     = $image['url'];
                    $thistitle = $image['title'];
                    $alt     = $image['alt'];
                    $caption = $image['caption'];       
                    $size    = 'ClientLogo' ;       
                    $thumb   = $image['sizes'][ $size ];    
                ?>

                <?php if ( get_sub_field('bp_client_link') ) : ?>
                    <a target="_blank" href="<?php the_sub_field('bp_client_link'); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" />
                    </a>
                <?php else: ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div><!-- .column -->

        <?php if( ($clientindex) %16 == "0") : $count = $count+1; ?>

            <?php if($logototal > ($count*16)) : ?>
                <div class="show-for-medium more-down-icon">
                    <a href="#section-<?php echo $count; ?>"><span class="more-text">More</span> <span class="more-arrow"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/arrow-down.png" alt="arrow-down-icon" /></span></a>
                </div>                              
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- .row --> 
    </div><!-- .section -->

        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php $i++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Not sure this is the only problem, but it seems like you're wrapping just the opening div tags in conditionals:
`<div class="section general-section section-<?php echo $title; ?> section-count-<?php echo $count; ?>" data-anchor="section-<?php echo $count; ?>" style="<?php echo $bg_background; ?>">       
        <div class="row small-up-4 medium-up-8 large-up-8 align-middle">`.

Comment: Conditional is there to close it too if you scroll down

Comment: Right, but you're calling `endif;` right after those opening tags.